# Deleting keyspace on hourly basis

Tags: cassandra

We are using cassandra as temporary storage for sending binary objects (like images) between modules. Sender saves object into Cassandra, and sends small message via RabbitMq. Receiver gets message and read object from Cassandra. To avoid need in repairs we create keyspaces each hours named like this "yyyy-MM-dd-HH". Removal script runs in Crontab each hour and deletes old keyspaces both from Cassandra, and disk.
This mechanism works great, except of rare cases when it seems that Cassandra tries to persist memtables exactly in same moment script is running. Then there is following exception (from /var/log/cassandra/system.log) and node crashes and requires restart. 
Can you please advise me what is the best way to deal with it? And by the way we can't use products like Redis or Memcache cause we need our capacity to be bounded by SSD and not RAM.

Exception:

*ERROR [FlushWriter:609] 2014-05-24 09:37:05,260 CassandraDaemon.java (line 198) Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:609,5,main]
FSWriteError in /var/lib/cassandra/data/ks_2014_05_24_07/cf_cortexer/ks_2014_05_24_07-cf_cortexer-tmp-jb-1-Filter.db
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.close(SSTableWriter.java:475)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.closeQuietly(FileUtils.java:212)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.abort(SSTableWriter.java:301)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:417)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:350)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/ks_2014_05_24_07/cf_cortexer/ks_2014_05_24_07-cf_cortexer-tmp-jb-1-Filter.db (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.close(SSTableWriter.java:466)
    ... 9 more*

Comment: Who don't you use TTL for your objects?

Comment: Doesn't this solution require intensive repairs for reclaiming disk space?

Comment: By the way, updating yaml commit_failure_policy value from stop to  ignore resolved the issue for me.